# Django apache mod-python setup (vista)

Tags: django, apache, settings, mod-python, vista64

I am trying to setup my development environment on my local vista machine (django+apache+mod-python+postgres) and for some reason I can't load the settings.

Everything works on the built-in server but not under apache.

**Here is my httpd.conf**

```
<Location "/">
      SetHandler python-program
      PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
      SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE movies.settings
      PythonOption django.root /movies
      PythonDebug On
      PythonPath "['C:/django'] + sys.path"
  </Location>
```

**And Error:**

```
ImportError at /

No module named main.urls

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named main.urls

Exception Location: 
C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software 
Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe
Python Version:     2.5.4
Python Path:    ['C:/django', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python25.zip', 
'C:\\Python25\\Lib', 'C:\\Python25\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\bin', 'C:\\Python25', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2/_externals']
```

Comment: Once you get past your module import problem, be aware that your setting of django.root is wrong. Since you are mounting the application at "/', don't include that 'PythonOption' directive at all. You only need to set django.root with mod_python when mounting at a sub URL, which is not what you are doing here.

BTW, Apache service often runs as a different user, so that user must have permissions to access your Python installation, your Django installation, and your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Where does your code for your project reside? The parent of the folder that contains your project should be on the Python path.  Assuming main is your project name, and it's in C:\django\projects\main\ you'd need to have c:\django\projects\ on your python path.

Either that, or main.urls should be movies.urls in your settings.py.

Comment: Where does your code for your project reside? 

C:/django/movies and it's on the python path

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked this question a couple of weeks ago, but if you're still looking for help, you might try [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).  If you have success, please report back here!